# Why on double grouping on ObjectId in mongodb aggregation I get null?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Trying to do double grouping like that (second group is meaning less but it's just as an example):

```
db.statement.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: {o:"$object", v:"$verb"},
    c: {$sum: 1}
  },
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.o",
    count: {$sum: "$c"}
  }
}).result
```

$object and $verb is ObjectIds. I got:

```
{
  "_id" : null,
  "count" : 0
}
```

Why _id is null?

Comment: please provide the exact syntax you use on your shell. This is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each $group phase needs an enclosing curly brace -- your second $group is missing the enclosing curly braces.  Try:

```
db.statement.aggregate( 
    { $group: { _id: {o:"$object", v:"$verb"}, c: {$sum: 1} } },  
    { $group: { _id: "$_id.o", count: {$sum: "$c"} } }
)
```